# Using Rest API to create a SendDefinition sending to a DataExtension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

We want to send an Email from an external Tool with the Marketingcloud.
The Email is completely defined in MC and there is also an Dataextension with all Targets in MC. Our prefered API is the REST API so my question is if it's possible to use the REST API to send to an Dataextension?
When i check code.exacttarget.com 
(https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sends/createDefinition.html)
i see that it is only possible to send to an Report or Campaign in EmailDefinition Targets.
So is there any way to send to a normal Marketingcloud Dataextension using the Rest API and if Yes what i had to use as Target?

Thanks a lot
Ronald

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to execute a triggered send via REST API based on a Data Extension. You should review the following technical article:

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html

The sample payload in the article will get you to your goal pretty quickly.

Cheers
-cc

Comment: Sorry, just had another look at your question and must admit that I misread it. I don't think there's currently a REST API call that allows you to perform a send definition. I only see the option with Automation Studio here:  1.  Create a send definition in Automation Studio and start the Automation via API (needs to be SOAP though) or 2. create the Automation as a Triggered Automation and have it started via a file drop on the ftp

Comment: Thanks a lot Christoph. So it seems to be impossible for now. So we will do it with the SOAP Api but without the Automation Studio Workaround.